# Size of int and float

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, floating-point-conversion

I have a question about the ranges of ints and floats:

If they both have the same size of 4 bytes, why do they have different ranges?

Answer (score 23):

They are totally different - typically `int` is just a straightforward 2's complement signed integer, while `float` is a single precision floating point representation with 23 bits of mantissa, 8 bits exponent and 1 bit sign (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Comment: +1 Of course, you know better than me those are just the usual representations.

Comment: Indeed - since it was evidently a noob question I thought it best to keep things simple.

Comment: @cnicutar Are you implying that a `float` can be represented arbitrarily?

Comment: @Andreas Brinck I am implying that the standard doesn't say those **have** to be the representations.

Comment: @Andreas, cnicutar: To clarify, the C standard doesn't require the implementation to use IEEE-754.

Comment: @Andreas Brinck - there are plenty of floating point formats apart from IEEE 754; back in the late Cretaceous I worked on a VAX, which used the VAX F format.  The C language standard doesn't care about the specific float format used by an implementation, it just mandates the minimum range and precision.

Answer (score 18):

They have different ranges of values because their contents are interpreted differently; in other words, they have different *representations*.

Floats and doubles are typically represented as something like

```
+-+-------+------------------------+
| |       |                        |
+-+-------+------------------------+
 ^    ^                ^
 |    |                |
 |    |                +--- significand
 |    +-- exponent
 |
 +---- sign bit
```

where you have 1 bit to represent the sign *s* (0 for positive, 1 for negative), some number of bits to represent an exponent *e*, and the remaining bits for a significand, or fraction *f*.  The value is being represented is *s * f * 2<sup>e</sup>*.

The *range* of values that can be represented is determined by the number of bits in the exponent;  the more bits in the exponent, the wider the range of possible values.

The *precision* (informally, the size of the gap between representable values) is determined by the number of bits in the significand.  Not all floating-point values can be represented exactly in a given number of bits.  The more bits you have in the significand, the smaller the gap between any two representable values.

Each bit in the significand represents 1/2<sup>*n*</sup>, where *n* is the bit number counting from the left:

```
 110100...
 ^^ ^
 || |  
 || +------ 1/2^4 = 0.0625
 || 
 |+-------- 1/2^2 = 0.25
 |
 +--------- 1/2^1 = 0.5
                    ------
                    0.8125
```

Here's a link everyone should have bookmarked: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 4):

Two types with the same size in bytes can have different ranges for sure.

For example, signed int and unsigned int are both 4 bytes, but one has one of its 32 bits reserved for the sign, which lowers the maximum value by a factor of 2 by default.  Also, the range is different because the one can be negative.  Floats on the other hand lose value range in favor of using some bits for decimal range.

Comment: "Floats [...] lose value range" makes it sound as if the largest number representable by a floating point number was smaller than the largest number representable by an integer number of the same size, which is definitely not true.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not specify the size in bytes, but it specifies minimum ranges that various integral types must be able to hold. You can infer minimum size in bytes from it.

Minimum ranges guaranteed by the standard (from "Integer Types In C and C++"):

```
signed char: -127 to 127
unsigned char: 0 to 255
"plain" char: -127 to 127 or 0 to 255 (depends on default char signedness)
signed short: -32767 to 32767
unsigned short: 0 to 65535
signed int: -32767 to 32767
unsigned int: 0 to 65535
signed long: -2147483647 to 2147483647
unsigned long: 0 to 4294967295
signed long long: -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807
unsigned long long: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```

Actual platform-specific range values are found in  in C, or  in C++ (or even better, templated std::numeric_limits in  header).

Standard only requires that:

`sizeof(short int) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long int)`

`float` does not have the same "resolution" as an `int` despite their seemingly similar size. `int` is 2's complement whereas `float` is made up of 23 bits Mantissa, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 bit of sign.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the actual question ?

Comment: `float` is not an integral type

Comment: @pmg: I know. Read the whole answer.

Comment: the range of float is 3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits)
in Visual C and int have –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
and both are of 4 bytes then why there is so large range difference and how ? acctually this is what I want to know

Comment: @Monkey: OK - you've edited it now to add a sentence about floats, but the original answer did not even mention floats.

Comment: @Paul : It was in there, it was just a long answer that probably through everyone off. It was there as a teaching point.

Comment: Evidently a number of other people saw the original answer prior to the edit when it didn't have the sentence about floats. No matter though, since you fixed it. You might want to take out most of the irrelevant stuff about different integer sizes and ranges though.

Comment: @atul: See my last sentence. They may be the same size but are made up differently.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the **representation of a number**, which is dependent upon some rules you (or somebody else) defines, and the way you use to **keep the number** in the computer (the bytes).

For example, you can use only one bit to keep a number, and decide that `0` represents -100, and `1` represents +100. Or that `0` represents .5 and `1` represents 1.0. The 2 things, the data and the meaning of the data, are independent.

Answer (score 1):

An integer is just a number...
It's range depends on the number of bits (different for a signed or unsigned integer).

A floating point number is a whole different thing.
It's just a convention about representing a floating point number in binary...

It's coded with a sign bit, an exponent field, and a mantissa.

Read the following article:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/float/

It will make you understand what are floating point values, from a binary perspective. The you'll understand the range thing...

Comment: To be pedantic, C integral types are also, like floating-point types, just "a convention about representation".  Also, you have a circular definition in your second paragraph!